# Laravel on subdomain gets a 403 Forbidden error. Because it cant find a index.php file which is located in the public/ folder

Tags: laravel, subdomain, http-status-code-403

I created an subdomain for my Laravel application and deployed it on it. (Example: sub.domain.com)

When I try to access `sub.domain.com` I get A `403 Error` because the index.php was not found and is located in the public/ folder of my project. I know that i can move all of the files from the public folder and put them in the root of the project, but is this the only way to accomplish this? I also tried to create a symlink, but that won't work for me either.

Is there a "Laravel solution" for this problem? (I am using `Laravel Framework 7.12.0`)

Answer (score 1):

You should point your subdomain to specific folder. If you are using shared hosting check your cPanel where subdomain is pointing. There should be Root directory for that subdomain and it should point to your public folder. Then with Laravel you can do your logic.

Another way is with htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Rewrites all URLS [Replace "example" with the actual domain, without the TLD (.com, .net, .biz, etc)]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub\.)?example\.

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

It depends where your subdomain is pointing at first. If it is outside your main domain you can't redirect it htaccess

Comment: Still feels al little bit 'hacky', but thx for your answer :)